# git merge gives priority to an older branch

Tags: git, merge

A few weeks ago my partner "Jon" opened a new branch to work on a new feature. Meanwhile the rest of the team worked a lot in a bunch of new features, we created new branchs and merge them and always the work was merge in (lets say) `branch-update` branch. But "Jon" havent completed yet, and he never updated his branch from our updated work. Now the moment to merge with "Jon" has come. Problem is that when I try to merge with Jon his work has priority over mine.

I have `branch-update` and `branch-jon`, if HEAD points to `branch-update` and I say `git merge branch-jon` the result is branch-jon has priority over a lot of files that are already updated, and jon never touched in his branch. if HEAD points to `branch-jon` and I say `git merge branch-update` the result still the same.

So, my question is if there is a way to inform git that `branch-update` has priority over `branch-jon`, and the merge should only bring me jon updated work?

Answer (score 14):

There is no such thing as "priority" in merges.  Well, there *can* be, but *you* assign it; you'll see what I mean in a moment.

Merging is about *combining* work.  To combine work, though, you and they, whoever they are, must share a common starting point.  Since Git is all about *commits*—files are just embedded inside commits—this common starting point is a *shared commit*.

Try using `git log --graph --decorate --online branch-update branch-jon`, for instance.  What you will see may be quite complicated; I'm going to draw something simple.  Git draws the graph with more recent commits towards the top, and earlier commits below; for space reasons, I tend to draw my graphs horizontally.

Remember that each commit is a full snapshot of *all* files, frozen in time—immutable—and contains the hash ID of its predecessor or *parent* commit.  This means that starting at the most recent commit, identified by some branch name, we—or Git—can work backwards, one commit at a time:

```
             I--J   <-- branch-update (HEAD)
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- branch-jon
```

In this (highly simplified, to the point of unrealistically simple) example, you and Jon have two commits each that you have made since the common starting point.  The actual common starting point is commit `H` (`H` is really some big ugly hash ID, which `git log --oneline` will print abbreviated).  By starting at your latest commit `J` and working backwards to `I` and then `H`, and starting at Jon's latest commit `L` and working backwards to `K` and then `H`, Git will *automatically* find this best-shared-common-commit.  Git calls this best shared commit the *merge base* of the merge operation.  (Note that commits `G` and `F` and so on are also shared; they're just not *best*.)

(Git might draw this graph as:

```
* abcdef0 (HEAD -> branch-update) your commit subject
* c9f1233 your previous commit subject
| * 5bf3149 (branch-jon) his commit subject
| * 78983fc his previous commit subject
|/
* 371820d shared commit subject line
[snip]
```

Despite the change in orientation, these two drawings represent the same graph.)

Your actual graph will be far more tangled.  It may not be clear where the merge base is.  You can have Git tell you which commit is (or, possible but unlikely, commits are) the merge base:

```
git merge-base --all branch-update branch-jon
```

If this produces multiple merge bases, the situation is a little more complicated, but usually you'll just see one commit hash ID as the output.

In any case, having located the merge base—let's just call it `H` as in my drawing—Git now has to compare the snapshot in `H`, the merge base, against *your* latest snapshot, `J`, to find out what you changed.  It also has to compare the snapshot in `H` against the other latest snapshot, to see what Jon changed.  So it runs two `git diff` commands:

- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-J`: what you changed
- `git diff --find-renames hash-of-H hash-of-L`: what Jon changed

Now Git actually *combines* the changes.  It starts by extracting all of the files from commit `H`—from the common starting point.  To those files, it applies your changes.  It also applies Jon's changes.  In some cases, applying is easy: for instance, if you changed files `F1` and `F2` and Jon didn't touch those files, the result is *your* `F1` and *your* `F2`.  If Jon touched `F3` and you didn't, the result is his `F3`.  Many other files in `H` are probably exactly the same in `J` and `L`, so you can't even tell whether Git is using `H`'s, `J`'s, or `L`'s.  But for a few files, such as `F4`, *both* you *and* Jon made some changes.

This is where `git merge` really has to work hard.  All the other cases, `git merge` got away with just taking some file from `H`, `J`, or `L`.  For these files—the ones that you *both* touched—Git really does have to *combine* the changes.

If you changed lines 10 through 15 of `F4`, Git takes *your* changes to those lines.  If Jon changed lines 20 through 25, Git takes *his* changes to those lines.  There's no *need* for priority: Git just takes *both* changes.

What if you *both* changed lines 30 through 35?  Well, if you both made the *same* change to those lines, Git just takes *one copy* of those changes, applying that one copy to the file from `H`.

But if both of you changed lines 30 through 35, *and* you made *different* changes, well, now there's a problem.  **This is where the priority that doesn't exist doesn't come in.**  By default, Git just declares a *merge conflict* and gives up on completing the merge.  It leaves you with a mess: you have, in your work-tree, a file containing *conflict markers* around the conflicting set of changes.  Git also leaves you with *all three* input files in the index.  It becomes your job, as the human operating the Git machinery, to fix up the mess.

This is also where the "priority" that *you* can select comes in.  If you are using the standard `recursive` merge strategy, you can use the `-X ours` or `-X theirs` arguments—which I call *eXtended arguments*, though Git calls them *strategy arguments*—to tell Git: *In the case of a conflict, pick my changes (`-X ours`) or his changes (`-X theirs`).*

#### Summary

The mistake most people make at first when thinking about `git merge` is thinking that there are only two inputs, and that running:

```
git diff branch-update branch-jon
```

tells you what's going to happen.  That's completely wrong!  There are *three* inputs to each merge: the current (`HEAD`) commit and its files, the other commit you supply (`branch-jon`), and the *merge base*.  Git finds the third input—which in an important sense is really the *first* input—on its own, from the *commit graph*.  The graph is all-important here.  The graph determines the merge base, and the merge base, when compared to the two branch tips, determines the outcome of the merge.

The merge process itself—the path by which Git arrives at the content that will go into the new merge—is symmetric.  It doesn't matter which `git diff` gets run first.  However, when you say `-X ours` or `-X theirs`, that breaks the symmetry: you're picking one side or the other to prevail when conflicts occur.

In the end, when Git makes a commit from the merged files, that, too, is asymmetric.  The *first* parent of the new commit is based on `HEAD`: whichever branch `HEAD` is attached-to, that branch's tip commit is the first parent of the new merge commit.  The *second* parent of the new commit is the other commit.  And of course, the new commit's hash ID goes through `HEAD` into the current branch, so that when we get new merge commit `M`, the *current* branch is the one that acquires it:

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M   <-- branch-update (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L   <-- branch-jon
```

Note that the existence of this merge commit, with its two parents, *changes the graph structure in a future merge*.  Now the best shared common commit between `branch-update` and `branch-jon` is commit `L`:

```
             I--J
            /    \
...--F--G--H      M--N--O   <-- branch-update (HEAD)
            \    /
             K--L--------P   <-- branch-jon
```

If you now run `git merge branch-jon`, Git will diff `L` vs `O` to find what we changed, and `L` vs `P` to find what they changed.

Comment: Very clear explanation.
TL;DR: you can use the `-X ours` or `-X theirs` arguments :)