# Does the order of multiple Git Merges matter?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Suppose I have three or more branches, a "master" branch M plus "feature" branches B1 and B2.

Does merging: B1 into M; B2 into M
always yield the same results for M as merging: B2 into M; B1 into M

Also if it doesnt, how could one ensure that the two different versions of M are made equal after the merging order to get the result was different?

Comment: Unless there are merge conflicts and *you* resolve them differently, no reason to expect a difference between these two cases. Also, note that you could very well merge them in one go rather than successively.

Comment: Why not try it out on a test repo?

Comment: @RomainValeri Thank you. Suppose there were conflicts and they haved been resolved differently. How could one afterwards equalize the two different M branches? Merging them together?

Comment: @LucasSpiller Diff them first, you might then see how one resolution or the other has something wrong. In your case I would try to discuss it with all people involved to avoid bad assumptions.

Comment: [Closely related, maybe a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55487337/1256452)

Comment: (On second scan: not a duplicate, you're asking about multiple separate `git merge` runs. Still *related* though.)

Comment: @LucasSpiller : do you have a more precise situation to address ? or is this just a general question about merging ?

Answer (score 0):

The generic answer is : you shouldn't assume that "merging B1 then B2" yields the exact same result as "merging B2 then B1", the order of "merge" operations can matter.

And anyway : you should not assume that a succesful merge means the code is ok ; you should always check with some extra steps : review the code, run the compiler/your build scripts, run your linters, run your unit tests, QA ...

---

As far as merging goes : some extra elements may allow you to know that the order does not matter

Say `B1` only modifies files in `backend/` and `B2` only in `frontend/` -- or more generally, if the modified files are completely disjoint -- then yes, they will commute ;

or if, when inspecting how a common file is modified, you can see that the diff chunks act on separate portions of the file(*), you may also deduce that you can merge in any order.

But once again : you will be better off merging (in any order) and then *testing* the result, rather than trying to rely on some commuting property.

---

(*) : not exactly true as stated, this would require a more formal definition